# WP_Query order by ASC with numeric data - zeros appear at end of list

Tags: wordpress

I have a list of meta data that I am sorting `ASC` using `WP_Query` and `meta_key`, but any number with a proceeding zero goes to the bottom of the list, I would like this to appear at the top instead. Can this be achieved using `WP_Query`?

An example of the data:

```
10:00
11:00
12:00
09:00
```

In the context of these being times, 09:00 should appear at the top.

I am using `pre_get_posts` to modify the query as the page is also using FacetWP which doesn't always play well with `WP_Query`. The code for this is:

```
function events_query( $query ) { 
    if( is_post_type_archive('events') ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
        $query->set( 'meta_key' , 'start_time' );
        $query->set( 'orderby' , 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'events_query' );
```

Comment: Add technical  description about what have you done so far.Paste your wp_query with meta query into question so users can check and answer you accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to query your posts by numeric value

```
function events_query( $query ) { 
    if( is_post_type_archive('events') ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'event' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
        $query->set( 'meta_key' , 'start_time' );
        $query->set( 'meta_type' , 'NUMERIC' );
        $query->set( 'orderby' , 'meta_value_numeric' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'events_query' )
```

I have tested it and Hope this will help.

Comment: This resulted in a 404 unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't test it, but try below code, it should work.

```
function events_query( $query ) { 
        if( is_post_type_archive('events') ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', 'event' );
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
            $query->set( 'meta_key' , 'start_time' );
            $query->set( 'orderby' , 'meta_value_num' );
            $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        }
        return $query;
    }
    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'events_query' );
```

Comment: This gets it very close, but when times end in 30 the order is not quite correct. e.g. 09:30 is shown before 09:00.

Comment: for that i suggest convert time into unixtime stap and store into database and then try it.